# Mono cannot find MySQL assembly reference

Tags: c#, linux, mono, .net-assembly, gac

I am having a hard time accessing *MySQL* through *Mono* on  Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

What I've done so far:

1. downloaded MySQL Connector and extracted the zip file in a directory
2. added `MySql.Data.dll` assembly to the gac
3. copied `MySql.Data.dll` in the directory where I have a test project
4. set `MONO_PATH` to the directory of my test project

and still when I am trying to compile I get

> The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing here?

Here is my test file,

```
using System;
using MySql.Data;

namespace Test
{
  public class MySqlTest
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
  }
}
```

and I compile it like this,

```
csc test.cs
```

Comment: What is your command line for compiling? Are you adding a reference to the assembly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489258/adding-assembly-references-for-compiling-with-developement-console

Comment: No @SamiKuhmonen I directly `csc test.cs`

Comment: Wait I minute... I've tried `csc -r:System.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:MySql.Data.dll test.cs` before but it didn't work. Now somehow it works. I have not a damn clue.

Comment: Why are you using `csc` directly? It's more common to call `msbuild`, along with a project file. That said, a good chunk of people are using .NET Core rather than Mono on Linux these days.

Comment: I am totally new to mono so I had no idea about `msbuild`. Saw at the official website that you compile using `csc` and went straing for that. (I use also .NET Core but now I must use mono @canton7)

Answer (score 1):

Need point to the assemblies directly at the compilation. This works if the dlls are present in the same directory as the source code.

For example,

```
csc -r:System.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:MySql.Data.dll test.cs
```